# Should my device combine local DNS and static DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp

Our linux based device was originally configured to use locally DHCP assigned DNS servers (in busybox/udhcpc.script). However after encountering a customer with this misconfigured, we changed the configuration to use static DNS servers (such as 8.8.8.8 and 1.1.1.1). Now we have a customer, presumably using something similar to a pi-hole, that expects devices to use local DNS servers, and this configuration isn't working for him.

Will we encounter any issues by mixing DHCP assigned DNS servers and static / cloudflare DNS servers?

Maybe I should accept that we may encounter issues regardless of what we choose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always use DHCP assigned DNS name servers.

If the customer has misconfigured those, then the customer likely experiences other networking related issues too, and the customer should fix their configuration.

Combining these isn't useful, because if either one of them fails, then there will be delays in name resolution. Finding out the reason for those delays likely requires substantial effort.